# Running with Packet Capture Permissions under Stack

Tags: linux, haskell, haskell-stack

Not sure if this is more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) so apologies if this is the case.

I am currently trying to capture packets using the [Network.Pcap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcap-0.4.5.2/docs/Network-Pcap.html) library and have written this wrapper function around it:

```
getRawPacket :: IO B.ByteString
getRawPacket = do
    deviceName <- lookupDev
    handle <- openLive deviceName 2048 False (-1) 
    setDirection handle Out
    nextBS handle >>= (\(_,p) -> return p)
```

I am using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) to manage the build process. When trying to run `getRawPacket` in ghci, starting it using `sudo stack ghci --allow-different-user`, I get expected packet data back. However while running as a normal user e.g. `testuser` in this example,
I get back the following message:

```
*Main Pcs.Capture> getRawPacket
*** Exception: user error (enp0s25: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted))
```

I have followed the steps on [this blog post](http://daydreamer66.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/rhel-how-can-non-root-users-can-run.html) but these haven't made any difference. Is it possible to give linux permissions to stack(/testuser/ghc?) to allow it to perform packet operations through ghci?

Also when producing a standalone executable with stack, how can I ensure that the executable can carry out packet capture? How could I apply these permissions as part of the build process?